# Any way to export webform node to other installation?

Tags: webforms

Is there anyway to export a webform node to another installation in D7? I need to export a webform node with all its components and webform settings.

**Updated:** I already  tried with Webform Share, but I can't get the "email" setting exported, this settings are just ignored. I have a very complex emails setting that I'd like to export as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Webform share](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_share) module (it is a helper module to prepopulate newly created webforms and to export / import webforms between sites), it may be helpful for this scenario as it provides the following feature:

> Example usage 1: Prepopulated webforms

Create a webform with the required components.
Export the webform
Edit the webform content type and paste in the content from the export (under Publishing options)
Use the standard node add content links and each new content item created should be prepopulated with the exported webform.

> Example usage 2: Synchronization of webforms

Export the webform that has the settings you want
Import these over the existing webform.

**Note**: Existing webform components are replaced with the new webform components. If a component is dropped or the key is renamed, you will no longer have access to any user submitted data.

Comment: Yes I did, but I can't get the "email" setting exported. I have a very complex emails setting that I'd like to export as well.

Answer (score 2):

We have had a lot of success exporting webforms just using Node Export module - https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [Webform Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_features) which aim is to ease webforms exportation. It currently is in beta release and it works only with webform 3.x.